# Align buttons with rows of treeview

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a interface like this:

[image: example of gui]

I want to stick to using tkinter.
One of my ideas is to use a Treeview for the left table. But I struggle to make the buttons on the right side to align with the rows of the table.
I tried to put an empty frame on top of the buttons, but can't seem to make it work.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class ButtonTree(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, items):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.items = items        
        self.buttons = self.create_buttons()
        self.tree = MyTree(self, items)

        self.tree.grid(column = 0, row = 0, rowspan = len(items)+1)
        self.empty_space = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.empty_space.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
        self.buttons.grid(column = 1, row = 1)        

    def create_buttons(self):
        buttons = ttk.Frame(self)
        for item in self.items:
            button = ttk.Button(buttons, text = "Do Something...")
            button.pack(side = tk.TOP)
        return buttons

class MyTree(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, parent, items):
        ttk.Treeview.__init__(self, parent, columns = ("A"))
        self.heading("A", text = "Some A")
        self.parent = parent
        self.items = items
        for item in self.items:
            self.insert(parent = "", index = "end", text = item, values = "hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    buttonTree = ButtonTree(root, ["Hello", "Bye"])
    buttonTree.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

One idea I had would be to get the size of the button and make the height of the rows in the table match the size of the button, but I could not find how to get that information from the buttons.

Another attempt I made was kind of a table with just frames and buttons. But the buttons always used a bit more vertical space than the frames and I could not keep them aligned.

How do I keep the buttons aligned with rows of the treeview?

Answer (score 3):

This gets them all in line:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class ButtonTree(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, items):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.items = items
        self.tree = MyTree(self, items)
        self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.N)
        self.buttons = ttk.Frame(self, width=100)
        self.buttons.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.N)
        print(self.tree.config())

    def create_buttons(self):
        self.update()
        so_far = header_height = 16 + 2
        ttk.Frame(self.buttons).place(in_=self.buttons, x=0, y=0, width=100, height=header_height)

        for item_name, item in zip(self.tree.get_children(), self.items):
            print(item_name, item,self.tree.bbox(item_name))
            button = ttk.Button(self.buttons, text = "Do Something...")
            h = self.tree.bbox(item_name)[-1]
            button.place(in_=self.buttons, x=0, y=so_far, width=100, height=h)
            so_far += h

        self.buttons["height"] = len(self.items)*20 + header_height

class MyTree(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, parent, items):
        ttk.Treeview.__init__(self, parent, columns = ("A"), padding=1)
        self.heading("A", text = "Some A")
        self.parent = parent
        self.items = items
        for item in self.items:
            self.insert(parent = "", index = "end", text = item, values = "hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    buttonTree = ButtonTree(root, list(range(10)))
    buttonTree.pack()
    buttonTree.create_buttons()
    root.mainloop()
```

Gives:

[image]

The item height is found by `Treeview.bbox(item)`. However, the buttons will not move when scrolled, and the header height is guessed. A more bulletproof solution would be to use [`Treeview.tag_bind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.tag_bind), but that will means that you will not have buttons, but clickable list items.